# Translation client side

Tags: magento2

In `app/code/MyModule/Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/steps/recipient/item/product-zone.html`

I have

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Hello World'"></span>
```

but when I look into the `js-translation.json` file, I can't find the translation.

I also have added the key `Hello World,Hello World translation` in the csv file.

From what I have read, this is a known issue with Knockout.js due to the file being an html and not a phtml.

How can I fix this ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add double quote in your CSV file around your translations. For exemple :

`"Hello World","Hello World translation"`

Client side translation are generated by finding strings in `.js` and `.html` files. That's why you should always use the `__('');` method to translate in phtml files.

Client side translation are generated on the fly in developer mode and by running static-content:deploy command in production mode.

To refresh it in developer mode you need to delete `/pub/static` folder content.

Try to follow this steps :
- Check that your Magento is in developer mode
- Add double quotes in your CSV file
- Delete `/pub/static/` folder content
- Refresh your page